# Spelling error: 'Arcade' instead of 'Arqade'

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, fun, spelling

I spotted an instance where it mistakenly says [Arcade instead of Arqade](https://www.google.com/maps/preview/@40.708628,-74.006674,3a,15y,218.48h,88.93t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1sNitQ1mwoGYMAAAQIt-Pp-Q!2e0!3e2). Given it's the name of the site, this is a pretty serious error.

Comment: I blame google auto-correct

Comment: I hope this is just a cacheing problem.

Comment: Interesting. \*picks off from that point and explores the rest of the building\*

Comment: @Thomas See if you can spot all 42 unicorns!

Comment: [42 that is a lot O_o](http://i.imgur.com/JS5nF9g.png)

Comment: @Blem no, I think he means unicorn dolls like [this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OD5lO.png). They're all over the place. ;)

Comment: Why is there a dinosaur in the other room?

Comment: @Loko I highly suspect they planted stuff especially for the occasion for us to go nuts, same way they planted things in the hats sprites both years. Very smart! :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have a feeling sometimes that the whole SE network is just an elaborate mechanism for mass trolling...

Comment: @ShadowWizard Aha I see.

Comment: I don't see a lock on that up-vote storage cabinet ... :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard [I am prety sure they do that, doubt this is normal work attire](http://i.imgur.com/8w2Hljj.png)

Comment: @Blem it would be awesome if it was, wouldn't it? :P

Comment: [A normal meeting at SE? and why are the heads not auto blured like in rest of the office](http://i.imgur.com/bBuBJ3U.png)

Comment: @Blem the heads are all publicly visible [here](http://stackexchange.com/about/team) anyway. Not sure what contents they blur and why, except for the screens of course that might reveal sensitive source code or secret projects. :)